# how to print background image on printer as watermark

Tags: html, image, background, watermark

i have one image background of table with following syntax

style="background-image(URL)"

the problem is when i print it on printer it did't print.

can you please tell me how to get this

image background also get it printed on paper as watermark.

i need any code not to ask every user to change the browse settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be configured from within the browser. When you open print options, there is an option asking you whether to print background images. :)

Comment: The OP specifically stated "I need any code not to ask every user to change the browser settings".

Answer (score 1):

As you might have noticed from the answers, browsers by default do not print background images. Also, there is no way to coerce all the visitor's browsers into printing the watermark.

A possible way to force the watermark to be printed is to create a div which is positioned under the content with multiple repeats of an IMG tag containing the watermark. This is horribly kludgy.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have an option to print backgrounds.  In FF 3.6.3, under File --> Page Setup --> Print Background (Colors and images)

Answer (score 0):

The users would probably not want to waste ink on a background anyways.

I would suggest using an absolutely positioned div with z-index of 0 as the wallpaper, absolutely positioned content div with z-index of 1 for content.

To alleviate the ink issue, you could use the css @media print directive to change the opacity of the background to somewhere between 5 and 10%, making it more of a watermark.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfxg3/

CSS:

```
@media print {
    #background{
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
  }

#background{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    background:#255;
    display:block;
    min-height:100%; 
    min-width:100%;
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    There is some content in here
</​div>
```

Comment: I notice another answer had been flagged as correct, though it did not answer the question. This is my shot.